# Using RegEx to search a table for missing information doesn't extract all matching values

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access-2010, multiple-matches

I am a little new to VBA, and I did try searching the forums for this topic but I am not sure I used the right words to search. Here is my question:

I am using VBA to extract missing information with regexp. Say I have a table with text which contains phone and fax numbers. I would like to collect the numbers into a table. So far, the code I have works OK, but when I have multiple numbers (say regular and 800 #s) for some reason, only one number is retrieved, not the others. How can I get all the results to be added to the table?

Query:

> SELECT regxtr([Table1]![field1]) AS phone FROM Table1;

VBA code for (regxtr)function:

```
Option Compare Database

Function regxtr(ByVal Target As String) As String 'Target is the field we are 'extracting from

Dim re As New RegExp
Dim oMatches As Object
Dim oMatch As Object
Dim n As Long
n = 0

'Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With re
.Global = True
.IgnoreCase = True
.Multiline = True
.Pattern = "(\d\d\d.\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\d)" 'keeping the pattern simple for now just to test
End With

    'test before executing
If re.Test(Target) = True Then
Set oMatches = re.Execute(Target)

         'attempt to get all matches. THIS IS WHERE I AM FAILING
For n = 0 To oMatches.Count - 1
Set oMatch = oMatches(n)

   regxtr = oMatch.Value
    n = n + 1  ' does this even belong here?

    Next
End If


End Function
```

How can I get to so all matches will populate the field [phone] in the query? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided sample data from the phone number field, and explained better exactly what is not working in your code.

Comment: In answer to your question `does this even belong here?` the answer is no. The `For` loop will automatically increment the value of `n` with each iteration. And like @alan said, some sample data and example output would be useful.

Comment: In your loop, you reset the value of regxtr each time: `regxtr = oMatch.Value`. So it would only ever hold one value at a time. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a correction in terminology. You're not looking for 'submatches' (also called 'capturing groups' in other regex implementations). You're looking for 'matches' for your regex, so you can drop the parentheses and just use `\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}` That said, this may be what you need:

```
Function regxtr(ByVal Target As String) As String 'Target is the field we are 'extracting from
Dim re As New RegExp
Dim oMatches As Object
Dim oMatch As Object

With re
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Multiline = True
    .Pattern = "\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}" 'keeping the pattern simple for now just to test
End With

If re.Test(Target) = True Then
    Set oMatches = re.Execute(Target)
    For Each oMatch In oMatches  'Note: you may get multiple matches because you set re.Global = True above, otherwise you would only get the first match
        regxtr = regxtr & " " & oMatch 'Note: this is awkward and not advisable as a way to return the values. This is just an example.
    Next oMatch
End If
End Function
```

As a test:

```
?regxtr("foo 993-242.1231bar994.425-1234hello987.234.2424 world 999.342-5252")
 993-242.1231 994.425-1234 987.234.2424 999.342-5252
```

Comment: Alan and JP, thank you for the quick response. 
Looks like the solution by Alan gets all the matches. 
Is there a way to get the numbers either one per row, or 
repeat the rest of the fields in the source table, so if 
table1 looks like:

company  address  phone
ABC company 123 Lala rd, 800-333-4444 or customer service: 444-555-6666

yields:

company  address  phone
ABC company 123 Lala rd, 800-333-4444  
ABC company 123 Lala rd, 444-555-666

I am OK with regex but the VBA is a new turn.

Well appreciating your help

Comment: @user1449493 You haven't provided enough information about your source table to add additional data to the phone numbers. You might want to ask a new question about that. In the meantime, if this answered your regex question, you might want to accept the answer.

Comment: Hi. As to source table, it is a flexible matter: I am using regex to extract company information for companies of interest for partnership which we have a list for. The ones that have partial information, I am trying to complete in the db. I guess we can call the db myDB, and table myTable - fields, domain, url contact_text, and phone, where contact_text is copy/pasted text from contact_us page on the web page. The address I get OK with the right patterns, as address there is only one, phones can be a few. We would like to keep phones (regular, and toll free) in one field keyed on domain thx

Comment: @user1449493 Hello. I see you're somewhat new to SO. Comments aren't really meant to ask additional questions, or take an answer in a new direction. I would suggest that you might create a new question with all relevant details, then I or someone else could probably help you. This question was about getting your regex to work. If the answer did that, you might want to accept it and then ask a new question about the additional issues you've raised. Comments aren't a good place for that. Cheers.